# Selection Sorting program showing abnormal results

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, math

I wrote a selection sort program in C++. I have checked and rechecked the code, but the logic is perfectly fine. But the code is not sorting the array properly:

```
    // Selection Sort

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline void swap( int& x, int& y) {
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main() {
    const int n = 10;
    int list[n];

    string line(14, '-');
    cout << '\n' << line << "\nSelection Sort\n" << line << '\n';
    cout << "Enter " << n << " elements:\n";

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        cin >> list[i];
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i ) {
        int small = i;
        for( int j = 1; j < n; ++j ) {
            if( list[j] < list[small] ) {
                small = j;
            }
        }
        if( list[small] < list[i] ) {
            swap( list[i], list[small]);
        }
    }

    cout << "Sorted Array:\n";
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        cout << list[i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? The algorithm of Selection sort is given here: [Selection Sort- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Sample input with 10 numbers:

> 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

Output:

> 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 8 16

Comment: Technically your program is not a valid C++ program, as C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you want an "array" that you set the size of at runtime, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Step through this in a debugger and find out at which point exactly it's not doing what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is surely wrong here:

```
for( int j = 1; j < n; ++j ) {
```

should be

```
for( int j = i+1; j < n; ++j ) {
```

Also, the condition at the end of the loop

```
if( list[small] < list[i] ) {
    swap( list[i], list[small]);
}
```

is excessive. It is satisfied by definition after the inner loop exits.

See: [Sorting algorithms - selection sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/selection-sort) for the pseudocode and a nicely animated demo on different kinds of data.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop of the sorting loop, you have written: `for( int j = 1; ...)`
Now, every time, the inner loop is *not* going from **1 to n-1**, but instead is going from **i+1 to n-1**
So change the loop to `for( int j = i+1; ...)`

Also, you may change the swapping condition to **small != i**, but this is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I've inspected your code and you have a logic error for the selection sort to succeed. In the inner loop, the initialization of the inner loop is always `j = 1`. This should change to:

```
for( int j = i+1; j < n; ++j ) {
        if( list[j] < list[small] ) {
            small = j;
        }
}
```

<del>and also change the condition value of your outer loop to `i < n` to ensure the loop goes from start to end.</del>

Comment: `i < n` is not required because with `i==n-1` the inner loop is going to iterate over a single element, which makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop should be

```
  for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
  {
    if( list[j] < list[small] ) {
        small = j;
    }
  }
```

And if they small is not equal to I variable then swap

```
  if(small != i)
  {
   swap();
  }
```

Comment: Wrong, see http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/selection-sort. The inner loop iterates from `past-the-i` element to the end of the array. The array up to `i` is already sorted.

Comment: i try this thats why i am giving ans ,there are many methods to do any code ,don't rely on only one

Comment: The algorithm called "selection sort" is well defined. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37a59d3fda61b676: your code fails the same way as OP's.

Comment: why dont you try the whole code? and then tell me the difference?

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int arr[5],i,j,temp,min;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
  cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl;
  cin>>arr[i];
 }
 cout<<endl;
 cout<<"Values before sorting"<<endl;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
 cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
 }
 cout<<endl;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
  min=i;
  for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
  {
   if(arr[j+1]>arr[min])
   min=j;
  }
  if(min!=i)
  {
   temp=arr[i];
   arr[i]=arr[min];
   arr[min]=temp;
  }
  
 }
 cout<<"Values after sorting"<<endl;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
  cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
 }
}

Comment: Ok, see this one where I applied both fixes you suggest: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7c2164e14263262 Still wrong.

Comment: Here is your code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3be03e834739d523 It produces wrong results and contains an out of bounds error. You way want to fix your answer or revoke it since it contains an error and doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: well i dont see problem in my problem ,its running well on my matchine ,where can i send you the snap?

Comment: pastebin.org will suffice

Comment: Yes, but it contains `for (j = i + 1; j <= 4; j++)`, while your answer above contains `for(j=0;j<n;j++)`! Please look closer. Change to `for(j=0;j<n;j++)` and see how it breaks.